# How to make accordion first tab open by default React JS

Tags: reactjs, accordion

I currently have an accordion component that works well although i need the first tab to be open be default (all tabs are closed on default currently). currently you click the "summary" and it displays the contents below by changing the "details" to have "open" as true. I simply want the first child to be open on default - not always open, just on the initial load until they click another tab.

Below is the code for the accordion component:

```
class AccordionLight extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: -1
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { children, left, right } = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;
    return (
      <div id="accordion-light">
        {children &&
          children.length > 0 &&
          children.map(child => {
            if (child.length) {
              child = child[0];
            }
            const { props } = child;
            if (props) {
              return (
                <details
                  key={props.label}
                  open={open && open.props && open.props.label === props.label}
                >
                  <summary
                    tabIndex={0}
                    role="tab"
                    onKeyPress={e => {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      this.setState({ open: open === child ? -1 : child });
                    }}
                    onClick={e => {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      this.setState({ open: open === child ? -1 : child });
                    }}
                  >
                    <h4>{props.label}</h4>
                    <p>{props.sub}</p>
                  </summary>
                  {child}
                </details>
              );
            }
            return '';
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
AccordionLight.defaultProps = {
  children: null
};
AccordionLight.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node), PropTypes.node])
};
export default AccordionLight;
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want.

```js
class AccordionLight extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { children, left, right } = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;
    return (
      <div id="accordion-light">
        {children &&
          children.length > 0 &&
          children.map((child, index) => {
            if (child.length) {
              child = child[0];
            }
            const { props } = child;
            if (props) {
              return (
                <details
                  key={props.label}
                  open={open === index}
                >
                  <summary
                    tabIndex={0}
                    role="tab"
                    onKeyPress={e => {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      this.setState({ open: index });
                    }}
                    onClick={e => {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      this.setState({ open: index });
                    }}
                  >
                    <h4>{props.label}</h4>
                    <p>{props.sub}</p>
                  </summary>
                  {child}
                </details>
              );
            }
            return '';
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AccordionLight>
    <p label="one label" sub="one sub">one body</p>
    <p label="two label" sub="two sub">two body</p>
    <p label="three label" sub="three sub">three body</p>
    <p label="four label" sub="four sub">four body</p> 
  </AccordionLight>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Basically I've kept track of which tab is currently open in state and initially set it to the first child

```
constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
   open: 0
 };
}
```

Then check the `open` against `index` to see if the current tab should be open in `map()`

```
<details
 key={props.label}
  open={open === index}
>
```

Then setting the `open` to the `index` of clicked tab

```
this.setState({ open: index });
```